# Unable to use Xdebug 3.0.2 with NetBeans 12.2, PHP 7.4, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: netbeans, xdebug, ubuntu-20.04, php-7.4

I think I've all tried but I just can't use Xdebug with NetBeans on Ubuntu 20.04, there's a message "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)" displayed at the bottom of the IDE.

If I use `phpinfo()`, I can see that Xdebug is enabled, here's my xdebug.ini configuration file :

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so

xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.discover_client_host=0
xdebug.client_port=9000
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

In NetBeans my settings in Options -> PHP -> Debugging are :

```
Debugger Port: 9000
Session ID : netbeans-xdebug
Maximum Data Length : 2048
Stop at First Line : unchecked
Watches and Balloon Evaluation : unchecked
Show Requested URLs : checked
Show Debugger Console : checked
```

I know that this question has been asked douzains of times but most of them are old and none of the answers are working.
This drives me crazy so any help would be appreciated !

-- Edit :

Here is the content of the xdebug.log file :

```
[21406] Log opened at 2021-01-21 12:42:36.233357
[21406] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
[21406] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '127.0.0.1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[21406] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: 127.0.0.1:9000 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(
[21406] Log closed at 2021-01-21 12:42:36.234607
```

And here is the outpout of xdebug_info() :

```
PHP
Build Configuration
Version 7.4.14
Debug Build no
Thread Safety   disabled
Settings
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed    /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-ffi.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
Directive   Local Value Master Value    Docs
xdebug.mode debug   debug   
xdebug.start_with_request   yes yes 
xdebug.start_upon_error default default 
xdebug.output_dir   /tmp    /tmp    
xdebug.trigger_value    no value    no value    
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value    
xdebug.filename_format  no value    no value    
xdebug.log  /var/log/xdebug.log /var/log/xdebug.log 
xdebug.log_level    7   7   
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128 
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512 
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3   
xdebug.max_nesting_level    256 256 
xdebug.cli_color    0   0   
xdebug.force_display_errors Off Off 
xdebug.force_error_reporting    0   0   
xdebug.halt_level   0   0   
xdebug.max_stack_frames -1  -1  
xdebug.show_error_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off 
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off 
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value    
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value    
xdebug.dump_globals On  On  
xdebug.dump_once    On  On  
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off 
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p   
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off 
xdebug.cloud_id no value    no value    
xdebug.client_host  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   
xdebug.client_port  9000    9000    
xdebug.discover_client_host Off Off 
xdebug.client_discovery_header  no value    no value    
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value    
xdebug.connect_timeout_ms   200 200 
xdebug.scream   Off Off 
xdebug.gc_stats_output_name gcstats.%p  gcstats.%p  
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c    
xdebug.trace_format 0   0   
xdebug.trace_options    0   0   
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off 
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
```

Comment: 1) Show whole Xdebug section of your `phpinfo()` output (or `xdebug_info()`_ captured in the same way as you are trying to debug (a web page or a CLI -- it's important) 2) Enable Xdebug log (do not point it into tmp folder, use something like `/var/log/...` or alike as temp paths on Ubuntu are virtualized per app/process), try to debug and then share the log -- it will tell where it tries to connect (if at all) and what the response is.

Comment: Your Xdebug config is OK. Try adding `xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"` anyway (maybe it's important for NetBeans).

Comment: **Your issue is:** accordingly to the log there is nobody listening on that port. I'm not NetBeans user so cannot say exactly what you need to do ... but double check that NetBeans is listening on that TCP 9000 port (e.g. use `netstat` or alike to see that). This is should checked be after you initiate debugging (Click "Debug File" or alike button (I guess check https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html#debuggingSession and later or similar guide -- I'm using PhpStorm and it's a bit different there)

Comment: We need more information. Is your Netbeans running on the same machine as your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just black magic but anyway, it works. Thanks a lot

If it can help anyone, I hadded the xdebug.idekey to my .ini file and to have it running :

1. In Netbeans I click on the "Debug Project" button, it starts waiting for xdebug
2. In my browser (Chromium) I have to launch the url manually to start debugging

I tried using Firefox instead of Chromium for debugging and it's working as expected.

Answer (score -1):

Just for information: in version 3, Xdebug's default debugging port has changed from 9000 to 9003.
Source : https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide, Step Debugging

Comment: This should rather be a comment. But SO does not allow for comments with less than 50 reputation, i know.